# How can I return an array of Laravel Eloquent model objects from a query that requires left join?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There are two tables, "users" and "posts".

Table "posts" has "user_id" as a foreign key.

How to write this equivalent in Eloquent, in a way that returns an array called $posts which is not simple PHP array but the Post class model objects?

```
SELECT posts.* 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN users 
ON posts.user_id = users.id 
ORDER BY users.registered_at, posts.created_at;
```

In other words, I want to return an array of model objects and not just flat data that comes from raw SQL.

Comment: Set up proper relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: You can also just use `$posts = Post::query()->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')->orderBy('users.registered_at')->orderBy('posts.created_at')->select('posts.*')->get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have setup proper relationships as suggested above, you can get your user model then get posts through that user.

Your user model should have a function like:

```
public function users(){
  return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

You could probably do something like this:

```
$posts = Posts::load('users') 
->orderBy('users.reregistered_at')
->orderBy('users.some_column')
->get();
```

This should return a collection of posts with their relations and orderBy what you need

Comment: I think the question is about trying to retrieve records with relations in one go. Your example does not show that. Also, setting up a relation like this and using `with` in the eloquent query is not the same, since still 2 queries are made in that case. A `join` query is beter in this particular question I think.

Comment: This would still return the collection of posts, if he wanted all the posts he could simply just get the post model and get the user through the relationship

Comment: Reading the question again, I think a collection of posts is exactly what he wants.

Comment: Hi, the goal is to return a list of Eloquent objects that are ordered by a column on a foreign table.

Comment: Updated my answer, you can do something like that, just go to the laravel docs its not difficult to find.

Comment: @JellyBean this does not seem to work - to load posts ordered by the value of the registered_at column on the user of the post, thanks for your help.